# How to configure YAJSW for dependency on remote service

Tags: yajsw

I am using YAJSW to create multiple services, where each one is a member of a cluster. When the services are on the same machine I am using the YAJSW configuration point

```
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.<n>
```

to ensure the master always starts first and it works great. I need to add more services on another machine. How can I configure the remote services to be dependent on the one master service?